# Cisco client to site VPN IPSEC

Tags: cisco, ipsec, vpn

I've set an EasyVPN on a cisco, when connected to the vpn i'm unable to use internet
even the default route is through the tun0 interface created by my VPN client vpnc.

Please how to connect to VPN and have internet ? to browse others sites ?

Comment: What kind of Cisco device, and how is it configured?

Comment: I found the answer, there is an option named split tunnel that permit to connect to internet when connected to VPN 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps274/products_configuration_example09186a0080819289.shtml

Comment: Right, but that's causing the client to access the internet directly instead of through the VPN - which may not be how you desire to have it function.  Both methods are possible.

Comment: Correct Shane, i was confused well i still looking for second method to have internet through the VPN

Comment: Sure - in which case, can you provide the information I asked for in my first comment?

Comment: My question was in general and not for a specific device, let say that it is a Cisco c870-advsecurityk9-mz.124-15.T13.bin

Comment: In general terms, you need to ensure that traffic bound for 0.0.0.0 is brought through the tunnel, that the tunneled traffic makes it through any relevant ACLs, and that it's NATing properly.  You'll need to provide configuration from your device if you're looking for any more specific detail.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your Cisco device is setup to have a default route to the other side of the tunnel as well.  I'll provide more info when I'm not on my mobile.